# update drush 6.0 to 6.5

Tags: drush

I have drush 6.0 and recently installed drush7 as well with composer. Now i would like to update drush 6.0 to latest release in drush version 6. Is there any work around to achieve?

Thanks,
Swaroop.

Comment: You can use `composer update` command to update packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [instructions](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installupdate---composer) say:

> To install Drush 6.x (stable):
>
> ```
> composer global require drush/drush:6.*
> ```

Assuming you installed drush that way (using composer):

> To update to a newer version (what you get depends on your
>   specification in ~/.composer/composer.json):
>
> ```
> composer global update
> ```